# false phpdoc errors in eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt

I currently use Eclipse Photon PDT for an old PHP application. In this application there's lot of phpdoc comments but some of them are marked as errors.

- for "@param unknown $form" => "unknown cannot be resolved to a type".
- idem for "@return Ambigous <multitype:string , multitype:>" => "Ambigous cannot be resolved to a type".

Does someone know how to disable these errors? (because of that all my project files are marked with the error icon and I cannot see which files really have errors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest short-term fix is to disable that level of error checking:

`Project -> Properties`

`PHP -> Validation -> Errors/Warnings`

`Enable project specific settings`

`Undefined type ->` change from `Error` to `Ignore`

Better long-term fix is to use the expected type of `mixed` when the type is unknown or could be most anything.